# How can I determine the current directory name in R?

Tags: r, command, dirname

The only solution I've encountered is to use regular expressions and recursively replace the first directory until you get a word with no slashes.

```
gsub("/\\w*/","/",gsub("/\\w*/","/",getwd()))
```

Is there anything slightly more elegant?  (and more portable?)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Your example code doesn't work for me, but you're probably looking for either `basename` or `dirname`:

```
> getwd()
[1] "C:/cvswork/data"
> basename(getwd())
[1] "data"
> dirname(getwd())
[1] "C:/cvswork"
```

Answer (score 7):

If you didn't know `basename` (and I didn't), you could have used this:

```
tail(strsplit(getwd(), "/")[[1]], 1)
```